# I got some error in this code for two file. One is workshop_connect.php and another is workshop_retrieve.php

Tags: php

```
$con = mysql_connect('HOSTNAME', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
```

I run with the above code and it shows the error below

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseIntegration-master\workshop_connect.php:3
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseIntegration-master\workshop_connect.php on
>   line 3
>       Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseIntegration-master\workshop_retrieve.php:3
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseIntegration-master\workshop_retrieve.php on
>   line 3

Comment: This extension (mysql_*) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: I guess you are using PHP7, the `mysql_*` api has been removed for ever. So you will have to either revert to PHP5.6.? or amend yuor code to use PDO or the `mysqli_*` api's

Comment: for all the code ahh

Answer (score 0):

> If you are use PHP 7+ MYSQL no longer exist, try MYSQLi

if you are using any 5.x version, follow below

Try checking if the PHP MySQL extension is enabled or not.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

if you cannot find mysql extension there, theme mysql extension is not enabled.

Locate php.ini file, and edit it.

find the line

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

and remove `;` from the line

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: have you restated you server